# Unable to get only the youtube video description by the following link using json

Tags: javascript, json, youtube-api

Hi am trying to get the youtube video details by using videoid but am not able to get description in this how can I get it.Here is my link

https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&format=json

Here is the json:

```
{
  "title": "Trololo",
  "width": 459,
  "height": 344,
  "thumbnail_height": 360,
  "html": "\u003ciframe width=\"459\" height=\"344\" src=\"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/iwGFalTRHDA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c\/iframe\u003e",
  "thumbnail_width": 480,
  "author_url": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/KamoKatt",
  "provider_name": "YouTube",
  "version": "1.0",
  "type": "video",
  "provider_url": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/",
  "author_name": "KamoKatt",
  "thumbnail_url": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/iwGFalTRHDA\/hqdefault.jpg"
}
```

Comment: have you checked this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241276/how-to-get-youtube-video-description-with-video-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the video id with this endpoint from Youtube's API.

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={VIDEO_ID}&fields=items/snippet/title,items/snippet/description&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` - [jlmcdonald](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241276/how-to-get-youtube-video-description-with-video-id)

for the video with the url:

`https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&format=json`

the video id would be `iwGFalTRHDA` and now all you need is to use your `API_KEY`. If you don't have one you can get one [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) by following the instructions and then enabling the youtube API and using the key given to you.

with this videoid and my api key (i havent put it below tho)

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=iwGFalTRHDA&fields=items/snippet/title,items/snippet/description&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

the result is this:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Trololo",
    "description": ""
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

here's a video with a description the video id is `e-5obm1G_FY` :

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Anjana Vakil: Learning Functional Programming with JavaScript - JSUnconf 2016",
    "description": "Slides: https://slidr.io/vakila/learning-functional-programming-with-javascript"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```